# Why is var_dump() saying a string is an object?

Tags: php, simplexml, var-dump

I'm using an Amazon API to retrieve product information and the response (converted to an object using `simplexml_load_string()`) looks like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Items] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [ASIN] => B00C9WDZIG
                    [ParentASIN] => B00C9WDZIG
                )
        )
)
```

The output of this:

```
var_dump($parsed_xml->Items->Item->ASIN);
var_dump($parsed_xml->Items->Item->ParentASIN);
```

is this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
  string 'B00C9WDZIG' (length=10)

object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
  string 'B00C9WDZIG' (length=10)
```

I'm confused because `var_dump()` is outputting objects instead of strings. Why is that? Aren't `ASIN` and `ParentASIN` string values inside of the third `SimpleXMLElement` object?

In other words, I expected the output to be:

```
string 'B00C9WDZIG' (length=10)

string 'B00C9WDZIG' (length=10)
```

And I'm confused why it wasn't.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: `var_dump` shows both the type that the value holds, and the value itself. `$test = array('1', '2'); var_dump($test);` will give `array(2) [0] => 1, [1] => 2`.

Comment: Don't know nothing about simplexml, but you said you converted it to an object, well the strings are members of that object. `var_dump` just gives you an acknowledgement about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SimpleXML is a chained object. It's deceptive because you can do something like

```
echo (string)$xml->tag;
```

And get the value of something like `<tag>value</tag>`. But `tag` is also an instance of SimpleXML because you might need to get the attributes or children still. So `var_dump` is correct.

Let me explain further. Here's some sample XML for you

```
<xml>
  <mytag>
    <skate>roll</skate>
    <surf>swim</surf>
  </mytag>
</xml>
```

When we dump this into SimpleXMLElement(SXE), what we get is an instance of SXE. So the top object is our overall wrapper `<xml>` and we'll say we dumped that into `$xml`. The next level down is `$xml->mytag`. This is ALSO an SXE object. So are `$xml->mytag->skate` and `$xml->mytag->surf`. If you do

```
var_dump($xml->mytag->surf);
```

It will tell you that as well. It needs to be this way because let's say we want to modify the XML. We can just jump straight into

```
$xml->mytag->addChild('skydive', 'fall');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Which outputs

```
<xml>
  <mytag>
    <skate>roll</skate>
    <surf>swim</surf>
    <skydive>fall</skydive>
  </mytag>
</xml>
```

Comment: Saved me answering.  More directly put: because `$parsed_xml->Items->Item->ASIN` is not a string.  It can be converted (implicitly or explicitly) to a string, but it's still an Object.

Comment: @cincodenada or Machavity: What type of objects are `ASIN` and `ParentASIN`, then? If they are objects and not strings, shouldn't `dump_var()` show the type?

Comment: As `var_dump` told you, they're all instances of [SimpleXMLElement](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). That's why, when you're parsing for the value of the tag, you have to typecast it as a `(string)` because the object itself is not actually a string.

Comment: Oh, I thought `var_dump()` was saying `Item` was a `SimpleXMLElement Object` and that `ASIN` and `ParentASIN` were properties/attributes of that object.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of the more wonky PHP objects for that reason. This is the only place I ever recommend typecasting an object as a string. But each node of your XML will be an object.

Comment: You told var_dump() to dump `ASIN`, there's no reason for it to tell you about `Item`.  It's telling you that `ASIN` is an object that *contains* a string, which is a little odd, but helpful if you know what you're looking at :)

Comment: So `ASIN` and `ParentASIN` are SXE objects, who both have a property with no name that has the value `B00C9WDZIG`? If so, I think that's what's tripping me up the most, because I thought properties always had to have names..